# "IIS: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.Exception.Message" when creating a https binding through SSL certificate and powershell

Tags: powershell, security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have written this method to use the installed SSL certificate and enable https binding in IIS. But when I am calling this method then I am error this error from Powershell.

```
IIS: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.Exception.Message
```

This is the function to enable binding. All the required variables I am reading from .json file

```
function IIS-SSL-SETUP {
    
    $Global:iisStatus = $started
    try {
        $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $PFX_PASSWORD -Force -AsPlainText
        Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $PFX_FILE_LOCATION Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password $pwd
        $pfx.import($PFX_FILE_LOCATION, $PFX_PASSWORD, "Exportable,PersistKeySet") 
        $store = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::Root, "localmachine")
        $store.open("MaxAllowed") 
        $store.add($pfx) 
        $store.close()
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        Set-Location IIS:\
        if ($null -eq (Get-WebBinding "MyServer" | Where-Object { $_.bindingInformation -eq "*:$($IIS_SSS_HTTPS_PORT):" })) {
            New-WebBinding -Name "MyServer" -IP "*" -Port $IIS_SSS_HTTPS_PORT -Protocol https
            Get-WebBinding -Port $IIS_SSS_HTTP_PORT -Name "MyServer" | Remove-WebBinding
            cd SslBindings
            dir
            $pfx.Import($PFX_FILE_LOCATION, $PFX_PASSWORD, 'DefaultKeySet')
            $certThumbprint = "\LocalMachine\My\$($pfx.Thumbprint)"
            get-item Cert:$certThumbprint | new-item 0.0.0.0!$($IIS_SSS_HTTPS_PORT) //I am getting this error at this line
            $Global:iisStatus = "Passed"
        }
        else {
            $Global:iisStatus = "Failed"
            $Global:iisMsg = "Port $($IIS_SSS_HTTPS_PORT) is already in use, please mention some different port number in sslConfig.json."
            $Global:iisMsgColor = "Yellow"
        }
    }
    catch {
        $Global:iisStatus = "Failed"
        $Global:iisMsgColor = "Red"
        $Global:iisMsg = "IIS: $_.Exception.Message"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh damn! I was creating new binding and then removing all of them as `IIS_SSS_HTTP_PORT ` was not defined. Thank you so much @CFou. This fixed my problem.

Comment: @CFou hello can you post your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mehul Parmar, as you asked, I have deleted my comment and moved it into an answer:

Is the `dir` command lists something ? It probably should in your case. My testing have no result and works well without error. You can test if the element already exists :

`if (-not (Test-Path 0.0.0.0!$($IIS_SSS_HTTPS_PORT)))`

`"MyServer"` is a weird name for a web site, don't forget that bindings are bound to sites not to server. One more thing : `Get-WebBinding -Port $IIS_SSS_HTTP_PORT -Name "MyServer" | Remove-WebBinding` will remove all bindings if `$IIS_SSS_HTTP_PORT` is not defined. May be you should prefer this one :

`Get-WebBinding -Protocol http -Name "MyServer" | Remove-WebBinding`